# Countable subsets of an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I believe it's true that if I have an uncountably infinite set $X$ and a countable subset $A$, then it's complement, $A^c$ is uncountable.

Is it also true that if I have an uncountable subset of $X$, called $B$, the complement of this set, $B^c$, is countable?

Comment: Also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in general, no. For a simple example, consider the uncountable set $[0,2)\subseteq\Bbb R$: it’s the union of the complementary subsets $[0,1)$ and $[1,2)$, which are clearly both uncountable.

Answer (score 1):

The set of non-negative numbers is uncountable, and its complement in $\mathbb R$, the set of negative numbers, is also uncountable.

Comment: I never knew that "numbers" is synonymous with "real numbers".

Comment: @AsafKaragila : Neither did I.  Why would you say such a thing?

Comment: Because the set of non-negative numbers could also mean $\{k\in\mathbb Z\mid k\geq 0\}$; or in $\mathbb Q$; or in the real closure of $\mathbb Q$; or in the computable numbers; or so on and so forth.

Comment: But I think the context makes clear what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think that the answer could benefit from a slightly improved choice of words, e.g. "The set of non-negative real numbers" or so. You have a typo anyway to correct ("and **is** complement" to "and **its** complement").

Answer (score 0):

> I believe it's true that if I have an uncountably infinite set $X$ and a
> countable subset $A$, then it's complement, $A^C$ is uncountable.

8 years later... I suppose my answer will help someone else down the road, as I aim to prove your belief that if $X$ is uncountable and $A \subset X$ is countable, then $A^C$ is uncountable.

I am assuming you've already proven that the union of countable sets is countable. Others have already given you excellent counterexamples to your question.

Suppose that $A^C$ is countable, as is $A$ by definition. Then $A^C \cup A = X$ is countable. But $X$ is uncountable which we defined. So $A^C$ must be uncountable.

Hope this solidifies your belief.