# Can we write every uncountable set $U$ as $V∪W$, where $V$ and $W$ are disjoint uncountable subsets of $U$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Is it true that for every uncountable set $U$, we can write $U=V∪W$, where $V$ and $W$ are disjoint uncountable subsets of $U$ ?

Comment: As I remarked in the comment on MO. This **was** asked before.

Comment: Also see my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/uncountable-subset-with-uncountable-complement-without-the-axiom-of-choice/146700#146700).

Comment: (In fact I urge the next person who votes to close as a duplicate to use the link from my second comment).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Please** search the site the next time you are told that this **was** asked before.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, assuming the axiom of choice. Without the axiom of choice one might have an [amorphous set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set). Such a set is uncountable in the sense that it is not finite, and there is no bijection between it and $\Bbb N$. However, it is not the disjoint union of any two infinite subsets.