# Propertie of uncountable sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I have a set M which is uncountable. Can I conclude that there exists a subset $A\subseteq M$ such that neither $A$ nor $M \backslash A$ is countable?

Comment: With Axiom of Choice, yes.

Comment: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853113/does-any-uncountable-set-contain-two-disjoint-uncountable-sets), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384619/can-we-write-every-uncountable-set-u-as-v%e2%88%aaw-where-v-and-w-are-disjoint) and [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/uncountable-subset-with-uncountable-complement-without-the-axiom-of-choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** (Assuming the Axiom of Choice) $M\cong \{0,1\}\times M$ for any infinite set $M$.

Comment: Could you explain why such an isomorphism existis? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Axiom of Choice, every cardinal is comparable to $|\mathbb R|$, so your uncountable set $M$ has an uncountable subset $M_0$ such that $|M_0|\le|\mathbb R|$. Thus it suffices to show that an uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ can be split into two disjoint uncountable sets.

In fact, for any uncountable set $M\subseteq\mathbb R$, there is a rational number $q$ such that both $\{x\in M:x\lt q\}$ and $\{x\in M:x\gt q\}$ are uncountable. (This uses the fact that a countable union of countable sets is countable, which also follows from the Axiom of Choice.)