# Cofinite Topology: Borel Algebra vs. Power Set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

*Being curious...*

Are there uncountable spaces such that any uncountable subset has countable complement:
$$\#\Omega>\aleph_0:\quad\#A>\aleph_0\implies\#A^\complement\leq\aleph_0\quad(A\subseteq\Omega)$$

If so then for these the Borel algebra induced by the cofinite topology is already the power set itself.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't this like asking whether there is an uncountable space that is actually smaller than $\mathbb{R}$ since $\mathbb{R}$ is 'too big' for this property to hold? If so, it might be equivalent to the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @GenericNickname: No, it's not the same at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every uncountable set can be written as the union of two disjoint uncountable sets.

See, for example, [Does any uncountable set contain two disjoint uncountable sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853113/does-any-uncountable-set-contain-two-disjoint-uncountable-sets)

Comment: Great, thanks. :D

Comment: @Freeze_S: I think you can say that every infinite set is the union of two disjoint copies of itself. And so you can say that a nonempty set is infinite if and only it is the union of two disjoint copies of itself.

Comment: Nitpick: this does use the axiom of choice. Without AC such a set might exist!