# Subset of an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For all uncountable set,

Is there an uncountable subset such that its complement is also uncountable?

How can I prove this?

Comment: @Elaqqad Infinite does not imply uncountable.

Comment: I misread the question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming AC the answer is yes. (I'm not sure what the answer is in ZF).

Hint: Think about even and odd ordinals, and how you might use their existence for your purposes. This actually proves a bit more namely that you can split any infinite set into two sets with cardinality equal to the original set.

Comment: what's meant by AC and ZF?

Comment: Without the axiom of choice it is consistent that the answer is negative.

Comment: @asaf I figured you could probably construct some annoying uncountable set with that property. Though I suppose you have try a bit since I guess you can't do it for the reals as the other answer helpfully points out?

Comment: [Been there, done that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/uncountable-subset-with-uncountable-complement-without-the-axiom-of-choice). The actual construction is a bit eeky. I can get into details if you want, I may have already done that, too.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know even and odd ordinals.