# Show that countable/co-countable sigma-algebra is strictly smaller than Powerset

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I have a question regarding the countable/co-countable $\sigma$-algebra. I will write first its definition:

**Example.** Let $X$ be an uncountable infinite set. Then
$$ \mathcal{A} = \{A \subseteq X\mid A\text{ is at most countable or } A^c\text{ is at most countable}\} $$
is a $\sigma$-algebra, which is strictly smaller than $\mathcal{P}(X) = 2^X$. (stated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Simple_set-based_examples))

Now to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is quite easy, but how can we prove that $\mathcal{A} \subsetneq \mathcal{P}(X)$?

With $X=\mathbb{R}$ we can write $B=(-\infty,0]$ with $B^c=(0,+\infty)$, both are uncountable, with
$$ B\in \mathcal{P}(X) \quad \text{ and }\quad B\notin \mathcal{A} $$
So $\mathcal{A} \subsetneq\mathcal{P}(X)$.
But with a general $X$ how can we do it?

Comment: While it is true that the cardinality is smaller, that's not what your statement means (which is even clearer if you look at wikipedia's statement).

Comment: The Wikipedia article says that the co-countable $\sigma$-algebra is distinct from the power set, not that it has a smaller cardinality.  (I don't know about the cardinality, I'm just pointing out that you seem to have misunderstood the statement.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

You have the right idea -- we want to find some subset $B$ of $X$ so that $B$ and $B^c$ are both uncountable. Intuitively it's clear that such a decomposition should exist, but it's hard to see how to get your hands on one without something like the order structure of $\mathbb{R}$.

One way to do this is with a bit of cardinal arithmetic. It turns out that for any infinite cardinal, $\lambda + \lambda = \lambda$. So using this fact, we can find bijections

$$X \cong \lambda \cong \lambda + \lambda$$

Since $\lambda + \lambda$ is (by definition) the size of the disjoint union of two sets of size $\lambda$, this gives us the desired decomposition (do you see how?).

As an aside, you're going to have to do *something* tricky like this, as without AC there *are* uncountable sets whose countable/cocountable algebra is the whole powerset algebra. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146700/655547).

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was hoping that there could be a simpler proof, showing the fact that every uncountable set $X$ has covering $X = A \cup A^c$ where $A,A^c$ uncountable.

Comment: @JonathanSchnell -- unfortunately, no such simpler proof exists. As I mentioned in my last comment, without some kind of argument relying on the axiom of choice, the theorem fails. Indeed [amorphous sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set) are uncountable sets which cannot even be written as a disjoint union of two infinite sets! It's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that these sets exist (and they make your desired result false), so you're going to need to use choice in some fundamental way.

Comment: Oh, okey many thanks ;-)